# Why does program terminate without taking input?

Tags: arrays, c, string

This is sample of my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void sum();
int main()
{
    char choice[4];
    do
    {
        sum();
        printf("\nDo You want to restart the program: yes or no:\n");
        fgets(choice, 4, stdin); //error point
    } while (choice[0] == 'y' || choice[0] == 'Y');
    printf("\nThanking You");
    return 0;
}
void sum()
{
    int a = 3, b = 4;
    printf("sum of two number is %d", a + b);
}
```

In this program, only in the 1st iteration of `while` does it ask for input in `choice` and, on the next iteration the program auto terminates by taking any value in `choice`.

Following is the result after execution of code:

```
sum of two number is 7
Do You want to restart the program: yes or no:
yes
sum of two number is 7
Do You want to restart the program: yes or no:

Thanking You
[Program finished]
```

I am unable to understand that it takes input in `choice` while I haven't used `scanf()` (which leaves the new line character in the buffer). It may be it takes input from buffer that may be whitespace or other characters, but I don't know from where it came?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program is leaving a newline in the input buffer after the first prompt because there's not enough room for it in the buffer.

On the first call to `fgets` you give the string "yes" followed by a newline.  The buffer has size 4 and you pass that size to `fgets` so it reads at most that many characters-1 to account for the terminating null byte.  So there is still a newline left in the buffer.

That newline gets read immediately the next time `fgets` is called.

You should enlarge your buffer to handle more characters.

Comment: but if I write **yes** then it's contains three character and then I press enter which gets converted into NULL character by fgets() , so it beomes 4 characters hen there is no chance of small size of array.

Comment: @Suraj No, there is no conversion of newline to null.  If your buffer had room for the newline it would be included in the string.  Make `choice` 5 or more element wide.

Comment: Thanks Got it. It means fgets() can also take newline character. If it is so then this is the reason behind that when we print a string then there is a *\n*  get printed in last of every string.

Answer (score 3):

Your `choice` array is not large enough to hold all the input from the first loop. The second argument to the `fgets` function (`4`) tells it to read *at most* 3 characters (and it then appends a `nul`-terminator to the input). So, it leaves the newline character in the input stream, and that is read in the second loop (by itself).

Just increase your `choice` array size and the input limit to 5 (or more):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
void sum();
int main()
{
    char choice[5]; // Increase space for newline and nul
    do {
        sum();
        printf("\nDo You want to restart the program: yes or no:\n");
        fgets(choice, 5, stdin); // Inputs 'y', 'e', 's' and newline (4 chars) and appends a nul.
    } while (choice[0] == 'y' || choice[0] == 'Y');
    printf("\nThanking You");
    return 0;
}
void sum()
{
    int a = 3, b = 4;
    printf("sum of two number is %d", a + b);
}
```

From [fgets - cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) (bolding mine):

> Reads **at most count - 1 characters** from the given file stream and
> stores them in the character array pointed to by str. Parsing stops if
> a newline character is found, in which case str will contain that
> newline character, or if end-of-file occurs. If bytes are read and no
> errors occur, writes a null character at the position immediately
> after the last character written to str.

Comment: I have studied that fgets() convert newline character to NULL character and printf() or puts() convert that NULL character to Newline, is it correct?

Comment: @Suraj. No, there is no conversion. In your code, the newline character isn't read in the first loop. Once 3 (4 - 1) characters have been read, the function stops reading and appends a nul-terminator to the input buffer. If you just typed "y" followed by the ENTER key, your code would work - the input would then be a buffer containing the 'y' character, a newline and a nul-terminator.

Comment: yes I got it. But I want to know that when we print a string then it always leaves a newline character then what is the reason behind it. we need to assign zero to the last element of the array to avoid that newline character.

Comment: @Suraj If you want `printf` to output a newline, then you have to tell it to (as you have done, using the `\n` in your code).

Comment: Ok Thanks. Got it